# SQL Database SELECT JOIN Query

Tags: sql

I can do this question with three tables. However, the extra table confuses me a lot. Here is the schema:

```
COURSE(CourseID, CourseName)
COURSEMODULES(CourseID, ModuleID)
MODULE (ModuleID, ModuleName, LecturerID)
LECTURER(LecturerID, FirstName, Surname, Email)
```

How would you ensure that more than one lecturer can teach on a module?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions about the data types contained in your schema. The following query will allow you to select only lecturers that are teaching more than 1 module:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ModuleName) AS number_of_modules_taught
    , FirstName
    , Surname
    , Email
    , CourseName
FROM 
    (SELECT
        l.FirstName
        , l.Surname
        , l.Email
        , c.CourseName
        , m.ModuleName
    FROM course c
        JOIN coursemodules cm ON c.CourseID = cm.CourseID
        JOIN module m ON cm.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
        JOIN lecturer l ON m.LecturerID = l.lecturerID
    ) AS modules_by_lecturer
GROUP BY 2, 3, 4, 5

HAVING COUNT(ModuleName) > 1
```

I've also made this available on SQL Fiddle for you to play around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f25d5/4

**Edit:** After the fact it occurred to me that you might actually care about loading the data into tables such that one lecturer can be mapped to more than one module. This is accomplished by allowing the `ModuleID` field to be unique, and mapping it to the same lecturer:

```
CREATE TABLE course (CourseID VARCHAR(20), CourseName VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE coursemodules (CourseID VARCHAR(20), ModuleID VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE module (ModuleID VARCHAR(20), ModuleName VARCHAR(100), LecturerID VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE lecturer (LecturerID VARCHAR(20), FirstName VARCHAR(50), Surname VARCHAR(50), Email VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO course (CourseID, CourseName) VALUES(12345, 'Pysics 101'),(23456, 'English 102'),(34567, 'Computer Science 306');
INSERT INTO coursemodules (CourseID, ModuleID) VALUES(12345, 13579),(12345, 79135),(23456, 35791),(34567, 57913);
INSERT INTO module (ModuleID, ModuleName, LecturerID) VALUES(13579, 'Newton\'s Laws', 24680),(79135, 'Thermodynamics', 24680),(35791, 'Chaucer', 46802),(57913, 'Lambda Functions in Java', 68024);
INSERT INTO lecturer (LecturerID, FirstName, Surname, Email) VALUES(24680, 'Stephen', 'Hawking', 'shawking@cambridge.com'), (80246, 'Neil', 'Tyson', 'ndtyson@amnh.org'),(46802, 'George', 'Martin', 'grrmartin@westeros.com'),(68024, 'Linus', 'Torvalds', 'lt@linux.org');
```